# How to connect UITableView to new created UITableView class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This is a very simple question. I was following a very basic youtube video but a little bit in different way. I have a UIViewController. There is a button on that called "History". When I press history I need to open a table view and show the history. Step I did is:

1. Drag and Drop a UITableViewController
2. Create a new file which is UITableViewController
3. So I have UITableViewController.h and UITableViewController.m file

Now I want to connect this UITableView to this new class and implement it. In the video said I must press Ctrl and drop in on the .h file to create an IBoulet

After pressing connect this must appear

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

But in my xcode when I drag and take it to the .h file there is no plus sign to connect them together.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

select your table view in interface builder. And at the right side of screen you will see object inspector menu. Write your custom class name here (like DinButton)[image]

Answer (score 2):

select table and then go to identity inspector in the right side of the xCode. (left to the Attribute inspector)

Then add your class name in the field "Class".

Thats it.